# SSMS connect via windows authentication when the server is not part of a domain

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssms

I have a test VM instance with SQL Server installed on it. It is not part of a domain, just a workgroup.

I want to use Integration Services, which I understand requires SSMS to log in using Windows Authentication.

1. Is it true that I have to use Windows Authentication to access SSIS?
   If not, how can I access this functionality?
2. If that is true, is there a way to log in via Windows Authentication
   without having the server on a domain?

Edit* - Since people tell me to 'just log in' and similar this is what I am doing - maybe I am going about this wrong?  Open SSMS, under Object Explorer going to Connect, selecting Integration Services.  As you can see, Authentication is greyed out, and from what I can tell by searching that is by design.

[image]

Comment: This is very helpful, though it does not address the point of my proof of concept since if we go this route I need DBAs to be able to run this package.  One of our old legacy dbs isn't on a domain either, so I'll still have the same problem.  It almost seems like I have to have this on a domain if others need to run anything I create, but this gets me going with my Spike.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your connection in SSIS just change the Authentication mode from "Windows Authentication" to "SQL Server Authentication" then type in the SQL user creds.

[image]

Comment: This is greyed out in SSMS 2014.  I am opening SSMS, In Object Explorer go to Connect, selecting Integration Services, and the Authentication method is greyed out, and from what I read that is by design.  Is there another way to get to this that I am missing?

Comment: @Mario the "Integration Services" in that connect to Server window is not what your looking for. If your trying to make a job to run an SSIS package you should connect to the "Database Engine" and use the SQL Server Agent there. If your trying to create an SSIS package you should use Visual Studio.

Comment: There are a few tutorials online that you can follow. You can one of the following or find your own on Google: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/lesson-1-create-a-project-and-basic-package-with-ssis https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/200/sql-server-integration-services-ssis-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

SSIS is a tool for moving data. It has no dependency on SSMS.

One can connect to SSMS using either windows or database authentication.

SSIS can connect to database resources using windows or database authentication.

An instance of SQL Server on the VM will accept connections using either windows or database authentication. As part of the set up of SQL Server, it adds the current user as a database admin. If this was not done, then [SO has directions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9889484/181965)

Now, if you need to access resources that are not local to the VM, then windows authentication is no longer an option as Computer\LocalUser won't have a mapping to Domain\User

And general blurbs about locations within SSIS that one needs to be concerned with authentication

### Integration Services Service

The installation media for SQL Server includes the SQL Server Integration Services *Service* It is a Windows service that does ... something. The best I can tell, it serves as a license check for executing SSIS packages outside of BIDS/Visual Studio/SSDT. It may do other things but who cares.

As a windows service, it will have a user associated to it. The default for 2014 at least is that it will create a user `NT Service\MsDtsServer120`

### SSIS ADO/OLE Connection Manager

SSIS encapsulates the security for connections as Connection Managers. These will allow you to specify the server (localhost) and the method for authentication. Again, either Windows or database authentication will work for you.

### Package Execution via SQL Agent

If you schedule a package execution via SQL Server's SQL Agent, it's going to execute as the account defined in the Agent setup portion of SQL Server (if using Windows Authentication).

```
SELECT servicename, service_account
FROM sys.dm_server_services WITH (NOLOCK) 
WHERE servicename LIKE '%agent%'
OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Connecting to Integration Services via SSMS allows you to connect to the SSIS package repository on the server in question. You can manage and even execute packages from there, but that's not a *requirement* for executing packages.

If you need to *create* a package, you need to install SQL Server Data Tools. You will presumably want to be able to connect to the target server during development, so you may want to install on the target server. When creating a package, as noted in existing answers, you can save a set of credentials to use when the package runs, or you can use the credentials of the user executing the package.

If you're creating a package that will run on multiple servers, you may want to add configuration details for the package in an XML file, or in a database on each server. This would allow you to store the configuration details for each server in the configuration file/DB, instead of in the SSIS package itself.

Packages can be executed using a command line tool (DTExec.exe) provided with SQL Server (I believe it's installed as part of the management tools (like SSMS) in 2014 - with SSMS being a separate tool, not sure where exactly such tools are now found in the latest versions of SQL Server).

If your DBAs can connect to this server using SSMS as admin users, they should be able to run the package with the same privileges. Note that whatever account they're running other may need appropriate file system privileges, if the package reads from or writes to the file system.